# Shows, with every $3\times 3$ matrices $A$ with all entries of $A\in\Bbb Z$, that: $\,\det(3A -2I) $ $\neq 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Shows, with every $3\times 3$ matrices $A$ with all entries of $A\in\Bbb Z$, that: $\,\det(3A -2I)\neq0.$

I have posted this question before, but I think that version is incorrect, so sorry to everyone for that. This is the correct version of that.

My approach with this is try to use the determinant formula, but it's really messy and complicate, I would love if anyone can give me a clear approach for this question

Thank you so much

Comment: Yes, use the determinant formula and consider the determinant modulo a certain prime. Then you are done. It is neither messy nor complicated. You should try this yourself. This will be much better than just reading an answer here.

Comment: I'm not so good at dealing with the modulo, can you give a clear solution for this, but thanks for your comment

Comment: The "modulo" solution is very clear. This is the advantage when dealing with integers. Do a few examples and you will see which integers are possible for the determinant.

Comment: @DietrichBurde "Very clear" is subjective. Even the fact that $f(n \bmod p) = f(n) \bmod p$ (or if you prefer, $m \equiv n \implies p(m) \equiv p(n)$) for a polynomial $f(x)$ and $n,p \in \Bbb Z$ (with $p > 0$) is not something that a student can be expected to intuit without a background that addressed modular arithmetic or finite fields in some capacity.

Comment: Hint: suppose $3Ax=2x$ for some integer vector $x$. Consider the GCD of all nonzero elements of the vector on each side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach was given in a comment. Here's an alternative approach that might be more intuitive and more suited to the mathematical tools you're familiar with. Rewrite the determinant in the form
$$
\det(3A - 2I) = \det\left(3\left[A - \frac 23 I\right]\right) = 3^3 \det\left(A - \frac 23 I \right).
$$
Thus, it suffices to show that $\det(A - \frac 23 I) \neq 0$. Note that the polynomial $p(x) = \det(A - x I)$ (the characteristic polynomial of $A$) has integer coefficients and a leading coefficient of $-1$. By the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem), this means that a rational number $x$ can only satisfy $p(x) = 0$ if $x$ is an integer.

Thus, the rational number $x = 2/3$ cannot satisfy $p(x) = 0$, which is to say that $\det(A - \frac 23 I) \neq 0$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Let me explain the approach in the comment in more detail. It uses the determinant formula, as you tried, but it is neither messy nor complicated.

Let $M=3A-2I$ and apply the [Rule of Sarrus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_Sarrus) for writing down the formula of $\det(M)$ in terms of the $9$ entries of $M$. It turns out that  we have a polynomial in the $9$ entries of $A$, which has coefficients in $\Bbb Z$, all divisible by three, except for the absolute term, which is $-8$. So we have
$$
\det(3A-2I)\equiv -8\equiv 1\bmod 3.
$$
This implies that the integer $\det(3A-2I)$ is nonzero.

Actually, we have
$$
\det(3A-2I)=27a_{11}a_{22}a_{33}-18a_{11}a_{22}+\cdots + 18a_{23}a_{32}+ 12a_{33}-8.
$$

Comment: Thank you so much